# TextToSpeech synthesizeToFile() method in android creates a blank file?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to save the output generated by `android tts` to `external storage`(ie. SD Card) using the `synthesizeToFile()` function, but it is unfortunately giving no an error

This is the code I tried:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification", "Anything", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {t1.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());}
        }
    });
    String toSpeak = "Some text to speak";
    t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    String envPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";
    String destFileName = envPath + "/" + "my_tts_file.wav";
    File fileTTS = new File(destFileName);
    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, toSpeak);
    t1.synthesizeToFile(toSpeak, myHashRender, fileTTS.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

But now it creating a blank `my_tts_file.wav` file (of 0 bytes) in the downloads directory.

Where exactly is the error?